# Why methods, defined in prototype, are shown in object itself?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Standard example for prototype inheritance learners:

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = 0;
}

Animal.prototype.stop = function() {
    this.speed = 0;
};

Animal.prototype.run = function(speed) {
    this.speed += speed;
};

function Rabbit(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = 0;
}

Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Rabbit.prototype.constructor = Rabbit;

Rabbit.prototype.jump = function() {
    this.speed++;
};

var rabbit = new Rabbit('Bunny');
```

Looking at Google Chrome debugger, I can see the following picture:
[image: Prototype JS inheritance]

What confuses me:

1. Prototype of `Rabbit` is set to `Animal`.
2. `jump()` method is defined on `Rabbit`'s prototype - not on a `Rabbit` itself.
3. Google Chrome shows `jump()` as part of `Rabbit`.

It seems reasonable, because I don't want `jump()` to become part of `Animal`, but non-logical, because I define `jump()` on instance of `Animal`.
Is there some special treatment for object in `prototype` property, like "set the object, defined in prototype as `__proto__`, but move all additional methods definition into child objects"? Or I get it wrong?

Comment: "Google Chrome shows jump() as part of Rabbit." — No, it doesn't. It shows it as part of `__proto__: Rabbit`, i.e. the prototype of Rabbit.

Comment: @Quentin, that's what confuses me. Because then from my understanding `Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` should set `__proto__` to `Animal`. In other words: are there 3 objects involved in inheritance: parent, child and some in-between prototype, which holds reference to parent and holds additional methods, needed for child?

Comment: No, it sets it to an *instance* of Animal.

Comment: @Quentin, ok if it sets it to an instance of Animal, why then Rabbit is shown? I can see, that Rabbit is also partly instance of Animal because of inheritance, but it seems like ruined abstraction: instead of abstract parent I get a concrete child.

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi `Rabbit` is shown as the constructor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

*1) Prototype of Rabbit is set to Animal:*
You indicate this with the following code:

```
Rabbit.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

`Object.create()` creates a new object with the prototype as the first argument.
It's used to create the prototypes chain between Animal and Rabbit.

*2) jump() method is defined on Rabbit's prototype - not on a Rabbit itself.*

It happens because you added this method exactly to the prototype, but **not** on the `Rabbit` instance.

```
Rabbit.prototype.jump = function() {
    this.speed++;
};
```

*3) Google Chrome shows jump() as part of Rabbit.*
Yes, the `jump()` method is a part of the Rabbit: inherited from Rabbit.prototype.

*4) It seems reasonable, because I don't want jump() to become part of Animal, but non-logical, because I define jump() on instance of Animal*
You define `jump()` on a instance of Animal (a new instance, because Object.create() was used, but still keeping the Animal prototype), which becomes the prototype of Rabbit.

*5)"set the object, defined in prototype as **proto**, but move all additional methods definition into child objects"*
It happens automatically on runtime, when an instance inherits properties and methods from the prototype object.

One thing that may be confusing is why Google console shows: `__proto__: Rabbit` and `__proto__: Animal`. Actually it displays the constructor function name, which is linked with the prototype objects.

Comment: So, to clarify: prototyped inheritance relies on intermediate object, which connects child and parent and is called "prototype"? E.g. in my case I can define `jump()` in 3 different parts: Rabbit itself, Rabbit prototype and Animal prototype and call each of them respectively: `rabbit.jump();`, `rabbit.__proto__.jump.call(rabbit);`, `rabbit.__proto__.__proto__.jump.call(rabbit);`

Comment: Yes, you can define `jump()` on all 3 steps: instance `new Rabbit()`, prototype `Rabbit.prototype` and prototype's prototype `Animal.prototype`. But the most sense is to use the step 2.

Answer (score -1):

You're only using the instance of Rabbit to get the prototype - but Animal has a reference to that same prototype - in essence, Rabbit extends Animal (or vice versa). So if you change the Rabbit's prototype, you change the Animal's prototype too.

You could define jump in the rabbit itself, not the prototype. Alternatively, you could set the Rabbit's prototype to a new Animal object and modify that.